SQLCipher "file is not a database" Error After Updating iOS App
I'm encountering an issue with SQLCipher in my iOS app after updating to a new version, which involves different workspaces of my app. The app uses SQLCipher(version: 3.1) to manage an encrypted SQLite database.The previous version (workspace2) had SQLCipher code that worked correctly. However, after updating to the new version (workspace1), I'm now receiving the error "file is not a database" when trying to access the database file.
Workspace Dependencies:
Previous Version:

Workspace1: There is no db related code here
Workspace2: Contains SQLCipher integration code and database operations.
App: Dependent on Workspace1 & 2 which includes additional app
logic and functionality.

New Version:

Workspace1: Contains SQLCipher integration code and database operations.

Workspace2: Depending on workspace1 and using few db operations.

App: Dependent on Workspace1 & 2 which includes additional app
logic and functionality.


Steps Taken:
Checked Database Path:

Confirmed that the database file exists at the specified path in the
Documents directory.

Ensured that the path is correct and the file is not missing.


Encryption Key:

Verified that the correct encryption key is used to open the
database.

The encryption key hasn't changed between app versions.


Database File Integrity:

Considered the possibility of database file corruption after the
update.

Not sure how to verify or fix any potential corruption.



This sounds like: an issue with the way you've integrated SQLCipher or mismatched SQLCipher major versions (you won't be able to open SQLCipher 3.x databases with SQLCipher 4.x by default as the encryption settings are different -- you'll need to use cipher_migrate or open it with compatibility settings: https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/upgrading-to-sqlcipher-4/3283). I'd recommend pulling the database off the device and attempting to open it with DB Browser for SQLite: https://sqlitebrowser.org If you're still stuck, create an simple example project on GitHub and post a link to it.

but here I am using 3.4 version only.

In both workspace 1 and workspace 2 implementations? My initial guess without seeing your code would be that it's some sort of issue with the way you've integrated SQLCipher. As mentioned in my previous comment, you should pull the database off the device, download DB Browser for SQLite and attempt to open it with that. Then if you're still stuck create a minimal project that reproduces the issue, upload it to GitHub and then post a link to it.

In both workspaces used 3.4 version only.

Did you pull the encrypted database off the device and attempt to open it with DB Browser for SQLite using SQLCipher 3 default encryption settings? What was the result?

I am able to open db file by using DB Browser. It has old data as well.

Sounds like a SQLCipher integration issue or conflicting dependencies with standard SQLite. Try to make a simple test project to reproduce the problem and narrow down what could be causing it. You can add dependencies one at a time to determine if one of them is causing the issue.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
